# Brick 2 x 2 cash register and tile 2 x 2 tape recorder sticker

Tags: sticker-identification

Recently after leaving my Dark Ages, I bought a bulk lot of LEGO and these parts with stickers were in it and were the only ones I couldn't find.

Is it possible to help? I used `Image Search Options` Firefox add-on but no luck.

[image: (1) Brick 2 x 2 with some cash register sticker in it]

[image: (2) Tile 2 x 2 with some sort of tape recorder sticker]

Comment: Though it is difficult to see given the quality of the pictures, but I do not believe these are official LEGO stickers. I cannot find any trace of them on BL, definitely not on the bricks in you pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these stickers are applied to the correct parts, you can search on Bricklink in the following categories: [Slope, Decorated](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=2&pg=18&catString=33&itemBrand=1000&catType=P) and [Tile, Decorated](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=2&pg=45&catString=39&itemBrand=1000&catType=P) (these links start at the pages where 2x2 slope and 2x2 tile first appear, respectively).

I didn't find anything looking like yours, which can mean one of three things:

- I didn't look hard enough (there certainly are *a lot* of decorated 2x2 tiles)
- These are *not* official LEGO stickers
- There *are* official LEGO stickers but applied on wrong parts.

I'm leaning towards them not being official stickers, but there's no real way to be sure until we find where they are from.

Comment: Thanks. I've used BrickStore, than selected "Part" and "Slope, Decorated". In the filter I used `"45 2 x 2"` and skimeed through all pages and couldn't find, so most likely it was a custom sticker.